# Python headless browser library for Oauth2 authentication from IPython console

Tags: python, web-browser, authentication

I want to be able to interact with my own Google accounts from an IPython console using Python Google APIs. The main obstacle to this is the Oauth user authentication/authorization process, which requires a song and dance session with the browser every time you start a session. I want to eliminate this song and dance and be able to connect to my accounst completely from within the IPython console with some simple initialization call

I have asked general question regarding this problem on SO, which currently has a 100 pt bounty:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39047595/simplest-way-authenticate-with-python-google-apis-to-access-own-accounts

Since asking that question I have come to think that a headless could be the solution. However I am not familiar with headless browsers and web programing is not my strong suit to begin with. There is also a large variety of Python headless browsers.
There are over a dozen libraries labeled as Python listed on https://github.com/dhamaniasad/HeadlessBrowsers .